# Javascript sort by nested object of array

Tags: javascript

```
    {
        "a": [
            {
            "value1": 34,
            "value2": 44
            },
            {
            "value1": 33,
            "value2": 10
            },
            {
            "value1": 52,
            "value2": 53
            }
        ],
        "b": [
            {
            "value1": 12,
            "value2": 43
            },
            {
            "value1": 23,
            "value2": 78
            },
            {
            "value1": 98,
            "value2": 36
            }
        ],
        "c": [
            {
            "value1": 56,
            "value2": 90
            },
            {
            "value1": 76,
            "value2": 50
            },
            {
            "value1": 20,
            "value2": 30
            }
        ]
    }
```

Here is my data.
I am trying to sort this data by "value2" of last object of array.

So. Here "value2" of "c" is 30 which is small so that object should come first.

The expected result is:

```
["c", "b", "a"]
```

So "value2" order is is 30 then 36 then 53

I can't think of any way to do this so asking here without attempt.

Please take a look how we can achieve this.

Comment: The outermost object is not array, its javascript object, and a,b, c are properties of it. So changing their order wont help much. Iterating over object properties, the order is not guaranteed. What you could do is, save the properties in a supporting array and in specific order.

Comment: I just needs as result

["c", "b", "a"]

Then i can manage

Comment: Question edited

Comment: @KiranSyoutubechannel my answer returns the result as it is before your editing.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in this way

```js
const data = {
  a: [
    {
      value1: 34,
      value2: 44,
    },
    {
      value1: 33,
      value2: 10,
    },
    {
      value1: 52,
      value2: 53,
    },
  ],
  b: [
    {
      value1: 12,
      value2: 43,
    },
    {
      value1: 23,
      value2: 78,
    },
    {
      value1: 98,
      value2: 36,
    },
  ],
  c: [
    {
      value1: 56,
      value2: 90,
    },
    {
      value1: 76,
      value2: 50,
    },
    {
      value1: 20,
      value2: 30,
    },
  ],
};

const sortData = (data) => {
  const obj = {};
  for (const i in data) {
    obj[i] = data[i][data[i].length - 1]["value2"];
  }
  return Object.entries(obj)
    .sort(([, a], [, b]) => a - b)
    .reduce((r, [k]) => ({ ...r, [k]: data[k] }), {});
};

const res = sortData(data);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Reduction to an object? Won't that undo the sort?

Comment: It just changing the values and returning the sorted data back.

Comment: As an object with keys in a specific order?

Comment: Yep. Correct !!

Comment: Changing the order of keys in an object isn't reliable and should not really be done. It's not really your solution's fault, but the question's, but the point still stands.

Comment: Yes. I agree with you @BrandonMcConnell.  I just suggest the solution. I have no idea why KiranSyoutubechannel  want to do it :)

Answer (score 0):

By nature, Objects don't inherently have a guaranteed sort order, however, we can try to work around that which should work in most cases.

Objects don't have a `.sort()` method, but we can use `Object.entries()` to temporarily convert the object to an array, apply our desired sorting logic, and then reconvert the final product to an object using `Object.fromEntries()`.

This should do what you're looking for:

```js
const sortObjectByValue2 = obj => Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).sort((a,b) => a[1].slice().reverse()[0].value2 - b[1].slice().reverse()[0].value2));
```

Here it is in action:

```js
const sortObjectByValue2 = obj => Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).sort((a,b) => a[1].slice().reverse()[0].value2 - b[1].slice().reverse()[0].value2));

const values = {
    a: [{
        value1: 34,
        value2: 44
    }, {
        value1: 33,
        value2: 10
    }, {
        value1: 52,
        value2: 53
    }],
    b: [{
        value1: 12,
        value2: 43
    }, {
        value1: 23,
        value2: 78
    }, {
        value1: 98,
        value2: 36
    }],
    c: [{
        value1: 56,
        value2: 90
    }, {
        value1: 76,
        value2: 50
    }, {
        value1: 20,
        value2: 30
    }]
}

console.log(sortObjectByValue2(values));
```

More information on `Object.entries()` and `Object.fromEntries()` can be found at these links:

- [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)
- [Object.fromEntries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries)

Comment: The answer assumes, a,b,c has always 3 elements.

Comment: The first part of this answer says that objects don't maintain key order, but the second part (fromEntries) ignores that correct statement.

Comment: @dahn Yes, objects don't reliably maintain sort order, and I would recommend for that reason to use a different object type such as an array, associative array, or a map, but if they truly need an object, this method will work and console log the object in the desired new order *in most cases* but it is not reliable and really should be avoided. So yes, a somewhat contradictory answer to a somewhat contradictory question haha

Comment: @RahulR. Very valid point — thanks! I've adjusted my solution to use `.slice().reverse()[0]` instead of `[2]` to make a shallow copy of the array being reversing it and grabbing the first (originally last) array element.

Comment: Your feedback about the sorting of objects is correct, but given the nature of the question, your solution makes good use of the Object entries and fromEntries methods.

Comment: @seanmitchell87. Can you please tell me the descending order on this approach ?

Comment: Sure @KiranSyoutubechannel. To get descending order instead of ascending order, just add an extra reverse statement after the `.sort()` statement, like this: `const sortObjectByValue2 = obj => Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).sort((a,b) => a[1].slice().reverse()[0].value2 - b[1].slice().reverse()[0].value2).reverse());`

Comment: @KiranSyoutubechannel if this^ works for you, please consider accepting my solution

Answer (score 0):

I think you can store the keys of the object to an array, and then sorted the array by the object vaule. Could use the code like the following:

```
const unordered  = {
    "a": [
        {
        "value1": 34,
        "value2": 44
        },
        {
        "value1": 33,
        "value2": 10
        },
        {
        "value1": 52,
        "value2": 53
        }
    ],
    "b": [
        {
        "value1": 12,
        "value2": 43
        },
        {
        "value1": 23,
        "value2": 78
        },
        {
        "value1": 98,
        "value2": 36
        }
    ],
    "c": [
        {
        "value1": 56,
        "value2": 90
        },
        {
        "value1": 76,
        "value2": 50
        },
        {
        "value1": 20,
        "value2": 30
        }
    ]
};

let ordered = Object.keys(unordered).sort((k1,k2)=>{
        let arr1 = unordered[k1];
        let arr2 = unordered[k2];
        if(arr1[arr1.length-1]["value2"]>arr2[arr2.length-1]["value2"]){
            return 1;
        }else{
            return -1;
        }
    });

console.log(ordered);
```